# Doing logistic regression for imbalanced dataset in R

Tags: r, logistic-regression, smote

I have a dataset for 1000 employees. This has 800 active employees and 200 who have quit.

I am trying to do a logistic regression to predict the risk of attrition.

My dataset is imbalanced because only 20% have quit. How do I balance out the data? I have heard of SMOTE in Python, but how do we bring that in R?

Thank you

Comment: Can you explain your goals?  There's not necessarily any need to balance, depending on what you are trying to do.  (Googling "R SMOTE" brings up a number of useful links ...)

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a specific programming question that's appropriate for Stack Overflow. If you have general questions about the appropriate use of various statistical methods, then you should ask such questions over at [stats.se] instead. You are more likely to get better answers there.

Comment: Thank you. Posted a more specific question now.